# Could the Chinese civilization have originated in Europe, and vice versa?

Tags: culture, alternate-history

The European and Asian cultures are unique to their respective continents.

But what if those cultures are switched around? Would it be possible for the Chinese civilization (language and philosophy) to have originated in Europe rather than Asia, and vice versa?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you mean what if the Chinese people started out in Europe and Europeans started out in China -- how would they have developed differently?  Why do you think there might be differences at all?  Can you add some detail to this question?

Comment: Not the race, the culture.  Did geography decide the culture or not?

Comment: So, you're asking how Europeans and Chinese would have developed differently in different locations?  You're assuming there's something inherent in the people who will develop each of those cultures?  Sorry, but this is still really unclear to me.  Please don't answer in comments; answer by [edit]ing the question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: What I wrote couldn't get any clearer.

Comment: I could recommend you this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spirit_of_the_Laws

Comment: Given how hard it is to reorganize the globe without changing anything, you may have to develop more of a world where this happened, paying attention to how it happened and its side effects.  I'm reminded of the book *Time's Eye* which dealt with such puzzle piece approaches, but on a more physical level.  It juxtaposed sections of time, from modern times to ice ages.  What happened?  Well, the first thing that happened were massive hurricane strength winds that no one expected.  Something about ice regions placed next to deserts.

Comment: The thing about cultures is that we don't really know how they "originate" - We do know how some real-world cultures changed and grew over time, but even that information is spotty and mostly recent. We're not even close to having a comprehensive idea of how cultures originate and grow. In other words, you've asked "could Culture X have originated in region B instead of region A," but we don't even know how it originated in region A, so... We haven't got any clue.

Comment: I'd suggest scale down the scope of the question, and try to focus on your world-building needs. World-builders on the site are not omniscient regarding evolution of culture (which is a hard subject in which to make predictions), and cannot answer the current question factually.

Comment: What's your definition of "culture?" Does your scenario involve teleporting the hunter-gatherers inhabiting Ukraine and northern China as of 6,000 BC? Just swapping their languages? Reversing the famed but controversial individualism of the West with the collectivism of the East? Transplanting their crops and animals? I beg to differ, your question could definitely get clearer.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades  No, no, no, no, none of all that!  There is a difference between race and culture.  Race is genetic.  Culture is not.  No teleportation involved, just a natural evolution of civilization in a different spot on Earth.  My question is clear enough--what more do you want?

Comment: @JonWDailey: whether your question is clear to *you* is irrelevant - it's obviously NOT to the people who would answer it. What I'm asking is that you state the change you have in mind. Define "culture," or define the exact change - such as swapping the physical people, or their language, or their crops - that you have in mind as the starting point for this scenario. You've asked a very vague question - you need to clarify it.

Comment: The Asians stay Asian.  The Whites stay White.  That's the racial end.  The switch is in the culture--language, architecture, philosophy, etc.

Comment: I would suggest that you focus on just one aspect, language (for example)

Comment: I am not going to see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

Jared Diamond tries to make the case that the Chinese couldn’t have become a world-dominating force like modern Europe in *Guns, Germs and Steel*, and I think it’s the weakest part of the book.  (He sometimes gives the impression that, in all of human history, nobody but Europeans ever missed an opportunity.)  Even he doesn’t argue that geographic determinism can explain the different course of European and Chinese history; he argues that China was too united.

Still, it does seem as if there would be some important differences: rice is native to Asia but not Europe and probably would not have become the staple crop unless Asian migrants had brought it with them.  It seems unlikely that Buddhism would have crossed from India into Europe as quickly as it did into China.  There would surely be some differences in who conquered whom due to geography or bad luck, and if you didn’t still have a Roman Empire that collapsed, leaving Normans to pick up a descendant of Latin and conquer the Saxons, you would definitely not get modern English.  Maybe the English and Scots live on Honshu and the Irish on Hokkaido, that’s kind of close, so maybe we stick Brittany around Korea, but then a bunch of stuff turns out different because England and France aren’t across a narrow channel from each other.  If France is in the same relative position, maybe putting it in Manchuria, then Spain can’t both have been anywhere next to it for Charlemagne to have set up his marches and have been conquered by Berber Muslims.  *Etc.*

Comment: Would you clarify on this?  Just to better understand where you're going with what you've said.

Comment: What would you like me to clarify?

Comment: I think my main example is that you asked, among other things, if the *languages* could have originated elsewhere.  You couldn’t get English (and Welsh and Scots) unless you replicated, at least in broad strokes, the history of Britain: the Anglo-Saxon invasion, the Danelaw, the annexation of Wales, the Norman Conquest, etc.  But start expanding that to every culture in Europe, and the maps aren’t similar enough to give you the same influences, I don’t think.

Comment: I think you may have missed Diamond's point: the reason, he argues (very briefly, I agree) that Europe pulled ahead of China after ~1500 AD was that because the geography of Europe was divided by many peninsulas and mountain ranges, therefore the region was politically divided, compared to China. The *cultures* of the two areas didn't enter into it.